# How can I run a file from my GitHub repo in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a GitHub repository, in which I have an executable file that I would like to run with a set of parameters. The file I need to run would follow the below format if run from the command line on a mac.

```
./p_executable -v test http://192.168.214.251:8000 username passw0rd
```

I have successfully been able to create a release pipeline that uses an Agent on my local machine and will run this executable as if I am running it straight from my terminal. For this, I just use a local agent and one stage that contains a single bash task.

However, I want to be able to run this file from any machine. So, I have added my p_executable file to my GitHub repo and linked my repo to my ADO account.

I have added GitHub as an artifact at the start of my release pipeline with the main branch that I would like to use.

However, I cannot work out how to make my bash script find the file.

I assume I can add GitHub as an artifact and that will check out my repo and then I can use the files within  like I would be able to in Jenkins for example.

Instead,  I get a

```
bash exited with code 127
```

when I try and add a resource and use one of the generic Azure DevOps agents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path of the executable file through the release [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---system) `System.ArtifactsDirectory`.

> The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a
> release. The directory is cleared before every deployment if it
> requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent. Same as
> `Agent.ReleaseDirectory` and `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`. Example: C:\agent_work\r1\a

Example: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\executable file

Comment: Hi Hugh, thanks for the info. I tried something like the following in my bash script task: 

$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/p_executable -v test http://192.168.214.251:8000 username passw0rd

but I still get an error saying the file is not found. I have tried with a Build artifact and a GitHub artifact. How do I make sure my repo actually is cloned?

Comment: `How do I make sure my repo actually is cloned?`You can check this in [release log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4D6y.png).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not seeing that 'Download artifacts' section, how do I get this?